# C Struct char members getting a weird values

Tags: c

I just started to play C and I bump into this problem. Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct person {
    int i;
    char name[100];
};

int main() {
    struct person p[2];

    clrscr();
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        printf("Enter i:\n");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].i);

        printf("Enter name:\n");
        gets(p[i].name);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++) {
        printf("ID: %d, Name: %c\n", p[j].i,p[j].name);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a sample ouput:

[image]

The problem is, all char members are not being asked for a value.

UPDATE:

btw, I am using Turbo C++ version 3 compiler.

Comment: You probably need to clear the input buffer after typing in a number (you press enter after the number, but you don't read that enter)

Comment: You should literally never use `gets`.

Comment: Your question is Windows specific. Posix, Linux, MacOS don't have `<conio.h>`

Comment: You should enable all warnings in your compiler. With GCC, this is done with the `-Wall` flag.

Comment: user Mystical got it right, but then when i refreshed the page, it was deleted.

Comment: @jun Actually, no I didn't. `fflush(stdin);` is not allowed. I have fixed my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to clear the input buffer to keep it from eating the newline.
2. Secondly, you need to change the format string to `%s`.

Here's the corrected code:

```
int main() {
    struct person p[2];

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        printf("Enter i:\n");

        scanf("%d",&p[i].i);

        //  Flush input buffer
        int ch;
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);


        printf("Enter name:\n");
        gets(p[i].name);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++) {
        printf("ID: %d, Name: %s\n", p[j].i,p[j].name);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

`%c` expects a `char`, but you're trying to pass in a string. It's undefined behavior to have mismatching types.

Output:

```
Enter i:
1
Enter name:
asdf
Enter i:
2
Enter name:
zxcv
ID: 1, Name: asdf
ID: 2, Name: zxcv
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour. `fflush` is defined only for output stream. [:)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Comment: Hi Mystical, for some strange reason when I accept your answer, a message pop-up and told me your answer was deleted. so what I did, I updated my question with your answer in it. thanks

Comment: @another.anon.coward pointed out the mistake I made. So I deleted to give me time to fix my answer. Although `fflush(stdin)` seems to work in MSVC, apparently it's undefined behavior by the standard.

Comment: I see. I really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 4):

You should print a string with `%s`; `%c` will interpret the pointer as a `char`. (Strictly, I believe the result is undefined behavior.)

Comment: Yeah I just did that, but it's still the same. it never asked for the member 'name'.

Comment: From your program's output, it seems it did.

Comment: Yes you are right about it. but the main issue was whenever a char members is asked for an input, it just jump to another loop.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to clear the input buffer after typing in a number (you press return after the number, but you don't read that return)

You can read the input stream until you read a `\n` after calling `scanf`:

```
while( ch = getchar() != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sscanf as scanf is deprecated.  You can also use sscanf for reading in strings as well, not just numbers.  Also, %c is for printing characters.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct person {
    int i;
    char name[100];
};

int main() {
    struct person p[2];

    clrscr();
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        printf("Enter i:\n");
        sscanf("%d", &p[i].i);

        printf("Enter name:\n");
        sscanf("%s", p[i].name);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++) {
        printf("ID: %d, Name: %s\n", p[j].i,p[j].name);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should either be very sure about what you write or use a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `%s` instead. Expression `p[j].name` is a *pointer* to an array of chars, so you can't print it with `%c`.